# How to use replace for only one term in a long expression in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, expression-manipulation

I am doing some Cauchy integration and in some intermediate steps I have something that looks like that:

```
(..many_terms...+I*\epsilon(k1-p1))/k1
```

where `\epsilon` is very small and positive. For my purpose I am only concerned with the sign in front of the `I*\epsilon` term. 
Now my question is: How can I tell Mathematica to substitute the `I*\epsilon(k1-p1)/k1` term by `-I*\epsilon` for `k1<p1` and `k1>0` .I tried using replace (/.) but it does not do anything. I would very much appreciate any help or insight since this situation shows up many times in what I am currently doing.

Comment: can you make up a MWE ?

Comment: Have you tried `expression //Conjugate //ComplexExpand`? This may be mathematically the more honest way to go.

Comment: And you want the substitution on *Mathematica* code or in $\LaTeX$ code? If in *Mathematica*, Why is your questions written with $\LaTeX$ code? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Perhaps Series[expr, {epsilon,, 0, 1}] or rather SeriesCoefficient